# Why showing red color even code is correct?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, react-redux

I am working on a react native app. I am using Visual Studio Code for my work. Why I am getting that red color alert in my code.

When I hover on it I get

```
"[ts] Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.
any"
```

I dont think there is any issue with my code but still It shows red. Can anybody tell me what is this issue.

[image: Red Colored]

Comment: The message tells you everything you need to know, right? Typescript thinks that your 'this.props' object doesn't have a property 'loading'.

Comment: It seems that you are using TypeScript and the way you are typing your code is probably wrong

Comment: @SteveBennett so what should I do to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your loading in props. Here is a small example:

```
type BooksTableProps = {
readonly data: Array<data>;
readonly pagination: Pagination;
readonly loading: boolean;
readonly error: string;  // or whatever

actions here      
}
```

Use the loading in your render method:

```
render() {
  const {
    loading,
    pagination,
    data,                
  } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>           
      <Table          
        columns={this.columns}
        dataSource={data}          
        loading={loading}
        pagination={pagination}
        onChange={this.handleTableChange}
      />
    </div>                
  )
}
```